# New to Java. How do I make it invalid for a user to input any integer?

Tags: java

Im new to java.

Need user to answer with a word  that can either start with a vowel or consonant. Any other symbols are invalid. If invalid input, program should print out 'neither vowel nor consonant'

Comment: Hi, glad you are here. To get a good response it would be better if you explain what you have tried so far and describe the problem that you are facing with the code that you have written. This way we can point you in the right direction. As it stands this question is too broad.

Comment: Lots of ways you "might" do this, the obvious one is using a regular expression, but that might be beyond your scope/experience.  Another way might be to check if the input value contains anything other than alphabetical characters.  A little messer, but, again, a number of ways you could do, going to check each character individual for a ascii range or simple from a list of "valid" characters

Answer (score 0):

After the user inputs, you want to take that data and compare it with all the invalid inputs. 
You can do this by creating an **array** of the invalid inputs, and running a **for loop** to compare each one. within the for loop, you want a conditional statement such as

```
for(int i = 0; i <= array.length();i++){
    if(userinput.charAt(0) == array[i]{ 
         System.out.println("neither vowel nor constant");
    }
}
```

The **charAt()** function returns the first letter or char at the beginning of the string & the **length()** function returns the length of the array!

**Hope this helps!**